# Unexpected output of printf for a string in C

Tags: c, pointers, char-pointer

Case 1:
When I take string input, it successfully gives the output, writing this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str;
    scanf("%s",&str);
    printf("%s",&str);
    return 0;
}
```

Case 2:
On the other hand, it throws a Runtime Error for this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str;
    scanf("%s",&str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

I found this thing peculiar, and want to know why it happens...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about **strings**, **pointers**, **arrays** and **dynamic memory allocation** together with **format specification**. Add cherry on cake by reading about *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Something around here is lacking memory and that is `str`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you didn't allocate memory for `str`, case 2 is the correct implementation.  Add a `str = malloc(50);` or similar before using it.  You are getting lucky in case 1 and just blasting some memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: Assume for a moment that case 1 is right. What makes you think that in case 2 you don't need to use `&` - case 1 and case 2 can not both be right. You can't just make it up as you go along. You need to use the correct types.

Comment: thank you everyone, i appreciate your answers and will get myself rectified

Comment: @eddiem, neither of the implementations is correct. Even if there were any memory associated to str, you would pass str to scanf(), not &str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those two cases are right.

**Case 1 only worked because you got lucky**, probably by giving a **short** string as input. Try something like `"bfjabfabjkbfjkasjkvasjkvjksbkjafbskjbfakbsjfbjasbfjasbfkjabsjfkbaksbfjasbfkja"` and you'll suffer a seg fault, most likely.

You should have a block of memory associated with `str`, either on the stack by declaring an array for it or on the heap `malloc`'ing memory for it.

And you shouldn't use the `&` operator.

So it would go like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[50];   // 50 is arbitrary
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

or like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char* str = malloc(50);   // 50 is arbitrary
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("%s",str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @YuriLaguardia

Comment: @yano Oops. Absolutely!

Comment: Sorry @yano. I am new to StackOverflow so not quite used to it. I thank you for sharing the correct code with me :)

Comment: @UddalakBhaduri No thanks to me (or need to apologize..?) this is all Yuri's code! Don't let the downvotes get you down, as long as you're learning something that's what matters. You got DVed because questions like this have been asked many, many times before.